# delete query with like and concatenate

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php and mysql and i am using delete query with CONCAT function, but it is showing some error.
My sql query is

```
$sql = "delete from  wp_users_friends where userid ='$username' 
and frid LIKE CONCAT('%',$frUserID)";
```

And the error is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

I am having a lot of trouble in this, try to help me

Comment: Sql server or mysql select one ???

Comment: **WARNING**: This looks [terrifyingly insecure](http://bobby-tables.com/) and for your sake I hope this is not on the public internet. You need to ensure any and all user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you are at serious risk of an application compromise.

Comment: yes all user parameters are properly escaped and there is no risk of application compromise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct it to:

```
$sql = "delete from  wp_users_friends where userid ='$username' 
and frid LIKE  '%$frUserID'";
```

MySQL [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function is made for concatenating the strings to make them a single string. Which is not required here.

If you want to find ids which start with `$frUserID`, use like keywords with wild card operator `%` in the beginning.

This operator `%` will search for all rows which have `frid` starting from `$frUserID`.

Answer (score 1):

Make your query as below:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM wp_users_friends WHERE userid ='$username' AND frid LIKE '%".$frUserID."'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `CONCAT()` for a `LIKE` expression, use a query like one of the other answers instead.

Just wanted to add, you should use *single quotes* (`'`) for the variable you pass into `CONCAT()`.

So instead of doing this :

```
$someSql = "CONCAT('%',$frUserID)";
```

You should do :

```
$sql = "CONCAT('%','$frUserID')";
```

Notice the single quotes around `$frUserId`.